# Convert Nested JSON into a DataFrame using Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a nested JSON where I need to convert into flattened DataFrame without defining or exploding any column names in it.

```scala
val df = sqlCtx.read.option("multiLine",true).json("test.json")
```

So this is how my data looks like  :

```
[
  {
    "symbol": “TEST3",
    "timestamp": "2019-05-07 16:00:00",
    "priceData": {
      "open": "1177.2600",
      "high": "1179.5500",
      "low": "1176.6700",
      "close": "1179.5500",
      "volume": "49478"
    }
  },
  {
    "symbol": “TEST4",
    "timestamp": "2019-05-07 16:00:00",
    "priceData": {
      "open": "189.5660",
      "high": "189.9100",
      "low": "189.5100",
      "close": "189.9100",
      "volume": "267986"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Which version of `Spark` are you using?

Comment: spark version = 2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using the `DataFrameFlattener` class implemented by [Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/introduction-to-dataframes-scala.html):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, StructType}

implicit class DataFrameFlattener(df: DataFrame) {
      def flattenSchema: DataFrame = {
        df.select(flatten(Nil, df.schema): _*)
      }

      protected def flatten(path: Seq[String], schema: DataType): Seq[Column] = schema match {
        case s: StructType => s.fields.flatMap(f => flatten(path :+ f.name, f.dataType))
        case other => col(path.map(n => s"`$n`").mkString(".")).as(path.mkString(".")) :: Nil
      }
    }

df.flattenSchema.show
```

And the output:

```
+---------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+------+-------------------+
|priceData.close|priceData.high|priceData.low|priceData.open|priceData.volume|symbol|          timestamp|
+---------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+------+-------------------+
|      1179.5500|     1179.5500|    1176.6700|     1177.2600|           49478| TEST3|2019-05-07 16:00:00|
|       189.9100|      189.9100|     189.5100|      189.5660|          267986| TEST4|2019-05-07 16:00:00|
+---------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+------+-------------------+
```

Or you can just execute a normal select:

```
df.select(
  "priceData.close", 
  "priceData.high", 
  "priceData.low", 
  "priceData.open", 
  "priceData.volume", 
  "symbol", 
  "timestamp").show
```

Output:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------------+
|    close|     high|      low|     open|volume|symbol|          timestamp|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------------+
|1179.5500|1179.5500|1176.6700|1177.2600| 49478| TEST3|2019-05-07 16:00:00|
| 189.9100| 189.9100| 189.5100| 189.5660|267986| TEST4|2019-05-07 16:00:00|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------------+
```